# apache config in apache server ,where to edit apache config in cpanel

Tags: apache, cpanel

I read a post which says Do this in the Apache config:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain2.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:3001/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001/
  </VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that i am new to these things(server configuration). Can you please tell me where to find apache config and how to input these lines into it.. i have linux vps cpanel + centos6 running an apache server .  because when i go to apache configuration in whm cpanel, i see global configuration,
DirectoryIndex Priority, and so on. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best I recommend is to ssh your Centos Server go to this default path (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf) and here you can make all possible changes .

So just ssh to server change to sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf you may use vi or gedit whatever you preferred and do the needful changes to the configuration  .

For Cpanel you can do it in two ways either via WHM or with CLI

I recommend here to do with CLI :

To modify the Apache configuration's include files via the command line interface (CLI), edit the appropriate configuration files in the /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/ directory.

Afterward run service httpd/apache2 restart

You can do it by editing .htaccess file as well but again it's not the best practices to be follow.

Please let me know if you need more clear picture on this.

Comment: thanks .actually i am running through a big problem. .socket.io.js:sourcemap:7 WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.quiznou.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=_w63A2sOBFHsHeG8AAAH' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
 i am getting this error when i am using sockets in my website. .is it due to apache config?

Comment: Well , the there are chances of config mismatch Work fine after switched host name to ip address sometimes .

Comment: Are you using Apache ProxyPass to send connections to node?

Comment: added the following line into /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (just before declaring ProxyPass, like in the config

Comment: ProxyPassMatch ^/sockjs/(.*)/websocket ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/$1/websocket

Comment: <VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName mysite.com
     ServerAlias www.mysite.com
     SSLEngine on
     SSLProxyEngine On
     ProxyRequests Off

Comment: SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.com.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.com.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.cer
     DocumentRoot /var/www/errorPages
     ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
     ProxyPass /503.html !
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:3999/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3999/

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:3999%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Sorry I have to do this in steps .  but after this it should be working .

Comment: Thanks a lot ..let me try now with these steps.

Comment: i have also created a .htaccess file in public_html ,which has :DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:49156/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:49156/$1 [P,L]

Comment: do i need to delete this .htaccess file before applying the steps said by you?

Comment: No No don't delet the .htaccess file just make changes in config file .

Comment: After this perform this action:  -sudo cp yourdomain-com.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourdomain-com.conf
# Enable all the necessary apache modules
-sudo a2enmod ssl                                  If you are enabling SSL on it
-sudo a2enmod proxy
-sudo a2enmod proxy_http
-sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
-sudo a2enmod rewrite
-sudo a2ensite yourdomain-com
-sudo service apache2 reload
-sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: i need to type sudo cp quiznou.com.conf and then enter? and then i need to go to /etc/apache2/sites-available/quiznou.com.conf ?

Comment: when i type the above command;it says : cp: cannot stat `quiznou.com.conf': No such file or directory